# How to pass variables of each item through to paypals cart when selecting paypal's 'add to cart' button?

Tags: php, sql, paypal, checkout

I am developing a website selling gardening products using PHP and SQL. The user searches for a plant, finds the one they want, clicks on it for more details and there they see an option to add to cart. I have signed up to Paypal's business account and used their add to cart button. But currently, when I try it out and click the button, it doesn't do anything. Obviously this is because know variables have been passed about that specific product. What do I need to do in order to get each item into the cart?

Comment: is this their integrated solution or does it take you offsite?

Comment: it takes you offsite as I have only opted for the standards payment and not the pro. Do I need the pro for this?

Comment: see the new edits below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### @QUESTION:

To impliment a normal POST to pass to standard form, follow this tutorial:
http://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/paypal-php-integration

### @INTEGRATED SOLUTION:

Integrated solutions will allow you to make these transactions without going offsite.
Using this method requires alot more security.

Comment: I dont really want to do an integrated solution because of the security issues. I just want paypal to handle the payment. I want the user to click on add to cart and have that product be visible in paypals cart. Which means I would need to have the id and price etc of that product to be passed to paypals cart? Is the link that you provided suitable for this?

Comment: yes. on a successful transaction you will be able to store transaction information per response.

Comment: I didnt say anything about storing the transaction information. I just want to know how to pass the variables to the paypal cart

Comment: you need to read it more closely, it gives very detailed explanation on how to make a request to the paypal server and store the response.